# Python: Restarting a loop after a failed condition

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

So I'm trying to run a for loop that goes as follows:

```
map = np.zeros((k,k))

for i in range(steps)
choose_random_location()
create_object()
    if !boundary_condition_abc:
        update_map()
    else:
    create_object()
    
    if !boundary_condition_wxy:
        update_map()
    else:
    create_object()
```

I know the code is wrong. I just wanted to place the logical flow of my code here. As it stands, `create_object()` in the else statement runs the risk of never being utilized. It could fail `boundary_condition_abc` and then fail `boudary_condition_wxy` and then the for loop would go to the next step without any update.

Instead, I would like the else conditions to restart the loop at the step it was on. So the else statement would be something like:

```
else:
start at the top of the loop on the same step
```

Is there anything like this in Python? What could be done instead?

I reran `create_object()` in the else loop. But it doesn't let me restart the loop. What I am looking for is something like a `continue` statement except that it doesn't raise the index of my `i`. I just want to start at the top of the loop.

Comment: The code is not just "wrong"; it has syntax errors.

Comment: You are in extreme danger of creating a never ending loop. Better to test for failure of conditions during the loop and act accordingly, when the loop terminates.

Comment: Please edit the code, there is something wrong with indentations and for loop's syntax, and maybe you should add more code lines, read that: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be looking for something like this:

```
i = 0
while i < 10:

    # do stuff

    if some_condition:
        i += 1
```

If `some_condition` at the bottom of the loop is not true, then `i` does not get incremented, and the `while` loop runs again with the same value of `i`.

Comment: Yeah! This was pretty much it. Kinda silly looking back at it. But I appreciate the time taken to reply to this.

Answer (score 0):

```
map = np.zeros((k,k))

i = 0
while i < steps:
    choose_random_location()
    create_object()
    if not boundary_condition_abc:
        update_map()
    else:
        create_object()
        continue
    
    if  not boundary_condition_wxy:
        update_map()
    else:
        create_object()
        continue
    i += 1
```

You can use a while loop to achieve what you say you want to.
The while loop flow works similar to the for loop, in that `i` moves from `0` to `steps` but here, the difference is that when you hit an `else` condition, there are `continue` statements.

`continue` makes the loop "skip" the current iteration of the loop, and go on to the next iteration. However, in this case, when continue is run, the `i += 1` at the end is not run, therefore it accomplishes your purpose.